# understanding behaviour of slicing in python

Tags: python, list, slice

The general syntax of slicing

```
[start:stop:step]
```

It will be evaluate `start:stop-1` and `step`(default 1)

```
>>> l = [x for x in range(5)]
>>> l[0:6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> l[1:-1] #case second
[1, 2, 3]
>>> l[1:-5] #case third
[]
```

Why in the *case third* it returns an empty list and also i don't understand in *case second* how step can be incremented by **1** if **stop** value in -ve.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop value in -ve". In particular what do you mean by -ve?

Comment: @Michael_H i mean -ve index

Answer (score -1):

```
l[-5] = 0
```

so doing:

```
l[1:-5]
```

is the same as doing:

```
l[1:0]
```

and like any other negative **range** (do not confuse with negative number!) - it will return an empty list

Comment: Ok, in this case as elements are consecutive integers staring from 0. Say `[x*2 for x in range(10)]` be the list. `l[-5]` is 10. `l[1:-5]` is not equal to `l[1:10]` and not an empty list as well.

Comment: @alfasin then why in _case second_ it returns an non-empty list. It will be same as `l[1:5]` i know that. I wanna to know how **step** will be incremented by **1** if **stop** is -ve and `range(1,-1)` returns an empty list.

Comment: `and like any other negative range - it will return an empty list`, that's not true, eg. `l[1:-1]` will give you `[1, 2, 3]` which is same as `l[1:4]`, only cases where the negative index overshoots the positive index in it's representation so that stop <= start will it give an empty list e,g, `l[1,0]` or `l[1:1`

Comment: @HarrishKumar as you noted: `l[1:-1]` is the same as `l[1:4]` - this is _not_ negative range ;)

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh see my previous comment, in this case `l[1:-1]` is _not_ negative range (don't mistake negative integer with negative range).

Comment: Guys, when you're using a negative _index_ it doesn't mean that what you're getting is necessarily a negative range: negative index `-i` translates into a positive index `len(l)-i` and this is the number that you should consider. `l[3:4]` is a positive range while `l[4:3]` is a negative range. If you write the `4` as `4` or as `-1` (when the length of the list is 5) is not the point. Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: @alfasin from ur comment i'll understand that python will convert `l[1:-1]` into `l[1:4]` at backend. Do have references/links in support of your answer.

Comment: @HarrishKumar https://www.pythoncentral.io/cutting-and-slicing-strings-in-python/ and https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html?highlight=negative%20index#what-s-a-negative-index also http://knowledgehills.com/python/negative-indexing-slicing-stepping-comparing-lists.htm